# Extra MR with my first name

Tags: tickets, bookings, check-in, air-india

I have one query related to name displayed on Air India website. 
There is extra "MR" with my first name on website and "Title" field is empty.

Can you please suggest on this and whether it is fine? My name in passport is :

First Name: KAUSHAL

Last Name : KISHOR

Name on Air India website and ticket is displayed as KISHOR,KAUSHALMR. Will this be an issue??